# Grep command to extract unique words

Tags: linux, grep

Here is my file.

```
this is temp1
this is temp2
this is temp3
this is temp1
this is tempabc
```

How to use grep command that while looking for pattern 'temp', the result should be displayed as only 'temp1, temp2, temp3, tempabc', only unique words.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Display only the unique words starting with `temp`:

```
$ grep -o '\btemp\w*' file | sort -u
temp1
temp2
temp3
tempabc
```

Comment: Good one, as it is almost the same as my answer I will delete mine. +1 for the `\b`, I did not know it was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` cannot do `uniq` alone, dirty and quick, you could:

```
grep -o '\btemp.*' file|awk '!a[$0]++'
```

e.g.

```
kent$  echo "this is temp1
this is temp2
this is temp3
this is temp1
this is tempabc"|grep -o '\btemp.*'|awk '!a[$0]++'
temp1
temp2
temp3
tempabc
```

actually you could do this in one short with awk.

Comment: won't work if there are additional words after the word containing `temp`.

Comment: @dogbane true, my regex is not so nice.  could be `\btemp\S*` in this way, all non-empty chars are included, e.g. `temp3@-#001` thx for pointing it out